# Javascript, insert String in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

i want to use this request in javascript

```
DELETE FROM temp_result WHERE 1;INSERT INTO 'temp_result' ('ID_Result') VALUES ('4871'),('4869'),('4756'),('4497'),('4296'),('4177'),('40'
),('2970'),('2729'),('2342'),('1221'),('838'),('200119770'),('200081730'),('200124125'),('20012738'),('200127381'),('200127374');'
```

I need the '' around the number because later the id will contain letters

I construct it like this :

```
 var query1 = "DELETE FROM temp_result WHERE 1;";
    var listid ="";
    for(var i in list){
        listid+="('"+list[i]+"'),"
    }

    var query2 = "INSERT INTO 'temp_result' ('ID_Result') VALUES "+listid.replace(/.$/,";");
    query = connection.escape(query1+query2);
```

But in the SQL error message, it turns out like this :

```
'\'DELETE FROM temp_result WHERE 1;INSERT INTO \\\'temp_result\\\' (\\\'ID_Result\\\') VALUES (\\\'4871\\\'),(\\\'4869\\\'),(\\\'4756\\\'),(\\\'4497\\\'),(\\\'4296\\\'),(\\\'4177
\\\'),(\\\'4047\\\'),(\\\'3606\\\'),(\\\'3518\\\'),(\\\'2970\\\'),(\\\'2729\\\'),(\\\'2342\\\'),(\\\'1221\\\'),(\\\'838\\\'),(\\\'200119770\\\'),(\\\'200081730\\\'),(\\\'200124125\\
\'),(\\\'200127385\\\'),(\\\'200127381\\\'),(\\\'200127374\\\');\''
```

Comment: for nuber no need single or double quotes change ```listid+="('"+list[i]+"')," ``` to ```listid +="("+list[i]+"),"```

Comment: For now they're just number but latter they will contain letter

Answer (score 0):

I would use connection.escape() only to escape items in list since the rest of the query is safe (does not contain code injected by user).

```
 var query1 = "DELETE FROM temp_result WHERE 1;";
    var listid ="";
    for(var i in list){
        listid+="('"+connection.escape(list[i])+"'),"
    }

    var query2 = "INSERT INTO 'temp_result' ('ID_Result') VALUES "+listid.replace(/.$/,";");
    query = query1+query2;
```

Comment: I get   'DELETE FROM temp_result WHERE 1;INSERT INTO \'temp_result\' (\'ID_Result\') VALUES (\'\'4871\'\'),(\'\'4869\'\'),(\'\'4756\'\'),(\'\'4497\'\'),(\'\'4296\'\'),(\'\'4177\'\'),(\'\
'4047\'\'),(\'\'3606\'\'),(\'\'3518\'\'),(\'\'2970\'\'),(\'\'2729\'\'),(\'\'2342\'\'),(\'\'1221\'\'),(\'\'838\'\'),(\'\'200119770\'\'),(\'\'200081730\'\'),(\'\'200124125\'\'),(\'\'2
00127385\'\'),(\'\'200127381\'\'),(\'\'200127374\'\');'                              and stil one \' by id when i remove the escape()

Comment: Can you print your list items? It may already contain the \' characters. Also, how do you print your query ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, it's not the INSERT. For whatever reason, it just doesn't accept simultaneous request, even though i used

```
  multilpleStatements : true
```